# При нажатии кнопки в форме "отправить",не появляется всплывающее окно

Tags: javascript, php, форма, всплывающее-окно

У меня есть форма обратной связи с модульным окном div на котором стоит изначально display:block. Нужно чтобы при нажатии на кнопку отправить,появлялось красивое окно об успешной отправке.Только вот заявка на почту отправляется ,а всплывающего окна нет.
вот моя форма

Имя
                             
                         
                         
                         Телефон
                            
                        
                            
                             E-mail
                            
                         
  
                         Отправить

вот модальное окно

```
<div id="modal">
               <h3>OK</h3>
           </div>
```

и свойства к нему

```
#modal{
   z-index: 999; 
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   position: absolute;
 display: none;
}
```

вот обработчик email на JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   //E-mail Ajax Send
   $("form").submit(function() { //Change
       var th = $(this);
       $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "mail.php", //Change
           data: th.serialize()
       }).done(function() {
           $("#modal").css("display", "block");
           setTimeout(function() {
               // Done Functions
               th.trigger("reset");
           }, 1000);
       });
       return false;
   });

});
```

и собственно PHP код

```
<?php

$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

//Script Foreach
$c = true;
if ( $method === 'POST' ) {

   $project_name = trim($_POST["project_name"]);
   $admin_email  = trim($_POST["admin_email"]);
   $form_subject = trim($_POST["form_subject"]);

   foreach ( $_POST as $key => $value ) {
       if ( $value != "" && $key != "project_name" && $key != "admin_email" && $key != "form_subject" ) {
           $message .= "
           " . ( ($c = !$c) ? '<tr>':'<tr style="background-color: #f8f8f8;">' ) . "
               <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'><b>$key</b></td>
               <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'>$value</td>
           </tr>
           ";
       }
   }
} else if ( $method === 'GET' ) {

   $project_name = trim($_GET["project_name"]);
   $admin_email  = trim($_GET["admin_email"]);
   $form_subject = trim($_GET["form_subject"]);

   foreach ( $_GET as $key => $value ) {
       if ( $value != "" && $key != "project_name" && $key != "admin_email" && $key != "form_subject" ) {
           $message .= "
           " . ( ($c = !$c) ? '<tr>':'<tr style="background-color: #f8f8f8;">' ) . "
               <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'><b>$key</b></td>
               <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'>$value</td>
           </tr>
           ";
       }
   }
}

$message = "<table style='width: 100%;'>$message</table>";

function adopt($text) {
   return '=?UTF-8?B?'.Base64_encode($text).'?=';
}

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL .
"Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8" . PHP_EOL .
'From: '.adopt($project_name).' <'.$admin_email.'>' . PHP_EOL .
'Reply-To: '.$admin_email.'' . PHP_EOL;

mail($admin_email, adopt($form_subject), $message, $headers );
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: может в done() надо инсерт полученных данных сделать в нужный див?